# How to return boolean if column contains integer value instead of searching millions of records using spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
var isIntContains = dataFrame.filter(col(colName).rlike("^\\d+")).count()
if (isIntContains > 0) { 
   print("It contains integer value in column provided")
 }
```

Where colName is coumn name passed dynamically.

Here, it iterates all rows upto the last one, continuing even if it finds an integer value. I want to write logic so it returns true/false if atleast one value in the column is an integer.

Comment: dataframe already has schema defined. You can just check datatype in schema.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a good question. Indeed it's not necessary to scan the entire dataset, because you want to break your search if 1 Integer has been found.

In the DataFrame API you could try:

```
var isIntContains:Boolean = 
dataframe.filter(col(colname).rlike("^\\d+")).take(1).size>0
```

But I've found that it's even faster using the RDD API:

```
var isIntContains : Boolean = dataframe.rdd
.mapPartitions(rows => {
  rows.find(row => row.getAs[String](colname).matches("^\\d+")) match {
   case Some(_) => Iterator(1)
   case None => Iterator.empty
  }
}).isEmpty
```

I've tried the above using randomly generated alphanumeric numbers of lenght 5 (so chances are quite low that the result is a Integer)

```
val dataframe = 
sparkContext.parallelize(
  (1 to 1000000)
   .map(_ => scala.util.Random.alphanumeric.take(5).mkString(""))
  )
.toDF("i")
.repartition(10)
.cache
```

Now if I check the dataframe for valid Integersusing your solution (i.e. using `count`) it takes ~ 1.5s while it takes only 0.7s using my first solution (DataFrame) and 0.6s using my second solution (RDD).

Comment: var isIntContains:Boolean = 
dataframe.filter(col(colname).rlike("^\\d+")).take(1).size>0    Here your not returning after finding integer value. After filtering your taking one value by .take(1) . This is not correct answer. I think we need to use udf.

Comment: @NiteenChougula How do you know what the optimizer is doing? The fact that it is faster than a plain `count` indicates that there is an early break, so I suspect not all data is filtered

Comment: Yes. I can agree but can u check what exactly I am looking for? "How to return boolean if column contains integer value instead of searching millions of records using spark dataframe"